# Need to link cmake project to dl library

Tags: unix, cmake

I am building a shared library that uses the dlopen and dlsym system calls.
When I build, I get the error

```
undefined reference to `dlopen`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It could be many reasons, when `dlopen` is not found during linking. One is that you doesn't link with `dl` library. You have good reputation, you definitely have searched this error message before posting a question. What have you tried?

Comment: Also, what about your code (`CMakeLists.txt` file)? You should provide it for get help.

Comment: Your question is bad. It lacks basic information like a minimal example containing your CMakeLists.txt file. The error message is not well formatted. How are we supposed to answer?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The answer turns out to be quite simple: cmake needs to be told to link with the DL libs, using `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` .

So, for any target that links with a library that uses dlopen, etc, invoke:

```
target_link_libraries(MY_TARGET LIB1 LIB2 ... LIBN ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```