# Link error in converting qmake to cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake

I have a simple project in Qt Creator (based on Qt 5.8) using RTI DDS Libraries. My project is **successfully built and linked** in Qt by qmake as the tool build.

Now I want to build my project with cmake build tool. So I write the below CmakeLists.txt. But I get the link error to RTI libraries. I have brought both qmake and cmake file. Please tell me what I am doing wrong;

qmake (.pro file):

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

DEFINES += "_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11

TARGET = untitled
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    datawriter.cpp \
    ../../../Repositories/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/myIDL/myIDL.cxx \
    ../../../Repositories/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/myIDL/myIDLImpl.cxx \
    ../../../Repositories/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/myIDL/myIDLImplPlugin.cxx

HEADERS += \
    datawriter.h \
    ../../../Repositories/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/myIDL/myIDL.hpp \
    ../../../Repositories/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/myIDL/myIDLImpl.h \
    ../../../Repositories/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/myIDL/myIDLImplPlugin.h


QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DRTI_UNIX
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DRTI_LINUX
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DRTI_64BIT

unix:LIBS += -L$$(NDDSHOME)/lib/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2 -lnddscd -lnddscored -lnddscpp2d -lrtidlcppd -lrtirsinfrastructured
INCLUDEPATH += .. \
                $$(NDDSHOME)/include/ndds/hpp \
                $$(NDDSHOME)/include \
                $$(NDDSHOME)/include/ndds \
                $$(NDDSHOME)/include/persistence \
                ../../../Repositories/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/myIDL \
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Publisher)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)

# Add RTI flags:
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DRTI_UNIX")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DRTI_LINUX")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DRTI_64BIT")

macro(add_idl_files LIBNAME)
    include_directories($ENV{HOME}/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/${LIBNAME})
    list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES $ENV{HOME}/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/${LIBNAME}/${LIBNAME}.cxx)
    list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES $ENV{HOME}/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/${LIBNAME}/${LIBNAME}Impl.cxx)
    list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES $ENV{HOME}/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/${LIBNAME}/${LIBNAME}ImplPlugin.cxx)
    list(APPEND HEADER_FILES $ENV{HOME}/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/${LIBNAME}/${LIBNAME}.hpp)
    list(APPEND HEADER_FILES $ENV{HOME}/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/${LIBNAME}/${LIBNAME}Impl.h)
    list(APPEND HEADER_FILES $ENV{HOME}/tests/r.karimi/Publisher/data/IDLs/${LIBNAME}/${LIBNAME}ImplPlugin.h)
endmacro()

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/DataWriter.cpp)
set(HEADER_FILES include/DataWriter.h)

include_directories(
        include
        # RTI
        $ENV{NDDSHOME}/include
        $ENV{NDDSHOME}/include/ndds
        $ENV{NDDSHOME}/include/ndds/hpp
        $ENV{NDDSHOME}/include/persistence
)

# Add DDS Libs
add_idl_files(myIDL)

set(
        LIBS
        #RTI
        nddscd
        nddscored
        nddscpp2d
        rtidlcppd
        rtirsinfrastructured
)

link_directories(
        $ENV{NDDSHOME}/lib/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2
)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

Link errors:

```
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlopen' 
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Reza

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to link cmake project to dl library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678965/need-to-link-cmake-project-to-dl-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlopen' 
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
.../libnddscored.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

These symbols are defined in `-ldl`. Simply add `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` to `target_link_libraries()`.