# How to set MKL on Linux with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I've used the same code provided in this link 
[How to setup MKL on linux with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200963/how-to-setup-mkl-on-linux-with-cmake?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But i'm getting this error 
Could NOT find MKL (missing: MKL_LIBRARIES MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS

I've tried to set MKLROOT to the following 
SET(ENV{MKLROOT} "/home/usr/intel/mkl:$ENV{MKLROOT}")

This is how findmkl.cmake module looks like without the line of code to set the environment for mklroot (i've used the same code in the link below)

https://gist.github.com/scivision/5108cf6ab1515f581a84cd9ad1ef72aa

i suspect the issue is setting the mklroot but not sure, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MKLROOT` is initially unset, the statement `SET(ENV{MKLROOT} "/home/usr/intel/mkl:$ENV{MKLROOT}")` sets `MKLROOT` equal to `/home/usr/intel/mkl:`, which is an incorrect format for the path. Instead, you could use

```
set(ENV{MKLROOT} "/home/usr/intel/mkl")
```

Alternatively, you can set the value of that environment variable externally, e.g.,

```
source /home/usr/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

and then run CMake. In that case, there is no need for the CMake `set` statement, which is a more portable solution.

**UPDATE:** As of 20th Feb 2021 `compilervars.sh` is not provided within Intel MKL and the environment should be set with the following command:

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh intel64
```

or wherever oneAPI is installed.

Comment: As it is 20th february 2021 ```compilervars.sh``` isn't provided within Intel MKL (one api) anymore.
And mkl is stored in ```/opt/intel/oneapi```.
Instead of ```/home/usr/intel/bin/compilervars.sh``` one should use ```source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh intel64```

Comment: @Jubick Thank you! I made the edit. Also keeping the original answer because that corresponds to the original question and is still relevant for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how long it exists but i only recently found this on [intel's online documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-guide-linux/2023-2/cmake-config-for-onemkl.html). Apparently there is a cmake config file included in the mkl package. Here is an example of how to use MKL according to the docs:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(oneMKL_Example LANGUAGES C)

set(MKL_ARCH intel64)
set(MKL_THREADING sequential)
set(MKL_INTERFACE lp64)
find_package(MKL CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS $ENV{MKLROOT})
message(STATUS "Imported oneMKL targets: ${MKL_IMPORTED_TARGETS}")

add_executable(myapp app.c)
target_compile_options(myapp PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:MKL::MKL,INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>)
target_include_directories(myapp PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:MKL::MKL,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
target_link_libraries(myapp PUBLIC $<LINK_ONLY:MKL::MKL>)
```

I have added some MKL options that are not in the link above. intel suggests that you read the top of the MKLConfig.cmake file for more info on these which is located in {ONEAPI_ROOT}/mkl/latest/lib/cmake/mkl/MKLConfig.cmake